# How to resolve "low graphics mode" during the installation of Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, installation

Please be patient, I am new to the Linux world.
I am running Win XP on an old desktop PC.
I want to install Ubuntu over or beside Windows.
The mobo is Matsonic MS9388E. The onboard graphics adapter is described as:
"Embedded 3D Ultra AGP VGA"
The PC has only 512MB memory installed.

I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 and burnt a CD.
I booted from the CD. 
It went straight into Linux boot type output on the screen - all looking 'normal'.
After a long time (5/10 minutes) I got the dreaded 'low graphics mode' message.
Clicking OK got me the 'what would you like to do' menu.
I tried the various options but can get nowhere.

I am concluding that the Ubuntu CD cannot support my onboard graphics.
Would this be a good assumption?  But what to do about it?
I see lots of 'sudo' talk in other posts - but I don't speak sudo :(

I've looked at this Question - but it only covers "low graphics mode" AFTER installation - my problem occurs DURING the installation.

- [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Comment: Yes, it's a support problem with your graphics card.  What other posts have you been reading?

Comment: All the ones I could find AND understand. I am afraid that talk of wubi and grub and sudo are just way over my head. I thought this was now a GUI world.  It seems to me that since Ubuntu is not installed, it will have nowhere to save any updates or downloads. So if I am to get new graphics drivers it must be via some external mechanism?

Comment: It is, but when you can't access the GUI because of problems like these you have no other option.

Comment: OK, firstly, thank you for your help - I do appreciate your time.  But when I type in some of these arcane commands I get pages of text usually ending in 'no space' messages. Are there any other Linux distributions which are more tolerant of different graphics chips?  Ger.

Comment: Since this is an older computer, I don't recommend using the regular Ubuntu.  It was made and designed with the newer, better graphics cards in mind.  Instead I recommend you try a lighter version.  Try either [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).  These will give you the same basic Ubuntu, but with a different desktop environment (or "GUI") that is easier on older hardware.  You will still be able to get support here if you need help.  You could also try [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/) although we don't support it here.  The people at [unix.se] do.

Comment: Thank you Seth.  I have just had a look at your profile.  As Alice would no doubt have said to the cat "I'm out of here". Back to the bosom of MS where all graphics cards are supported ;) Take care.

Comment: @gerdalton - given your last comment I have closed this question.  If you wish to at least have a crack at installation with our help, please flag and ask for this to be reopened.